# Cloudposse CodeFresh -- pull-request pipeline spec -- terminate without setting status to "Failed"

Tags: github, continuous-integration, pipeline, codefresh, cloudposse

### I have a CodeFresh, GitHub pull-request pipeline.

There are 2 scenarios where a **PR marks as "Failed"**, when **ideally it would show as "Pending"** or no status.

#### Scenario 1:

When a new event is triggered, it terminates the previous build (as expected)

> Build was terminated by pipeline policy - new build triggered by pull-request on branch `<my-branch>`

This is all great, *but* the build then shows as "Failed" on GitHub.  Theoretically, the new build would undo the "failed" status, but this can take quite some time, and it is difficult to follow what the latest running build is.  My `terminationPolicy` spec looks like this:

```yaml
terminationPolicy:
  - type: branch
    event: onCreate
```

Termination Policy Docs:
https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/integrations/codefresh-api/?#full-pipeline-specification

#### Scenario 2:

We want to bypass the build based on labels applied.  Ex: `"skip-test"`, or be able to run tests without the limitations of the `branchRegex`.

```yaml
steps:
  harakiri:
    ...
    commands:
      - codefresh terminate ${{CF_BUILD_ID}}
    when:
      condition:
        any:
          isWorkInProgress: "match('${{CF_PULL_REQUEST_LABELS}}', 'WIP', false) == true"
```

Again, works great.  But marks the PR as "failed".

---

If there were a way to inject a command into either of these, I could work with that. But how we have it laid out, it requires entire step to change the status to "Pending".  (so I can't simply add an extra "command" to the `harakiri` step)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1**

I can suggest you use github-status-updater with hooks (instead of default status updates)

So basically it will set `pending` status at the build start (and will keep this status if it's terminated by policy).

```yaml
hooks:
  on_success:
    title: Set GitHub deployment status to "success"
    image: cloudposse/github-status-updater
    environment:
      - GITHUB_ACTION=update_state
      - GITHUB_TOKEN=${{GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      - GITHUB_OWNER=${{CF_REPO_OWNER}}
      - GITHUB_REPO=${{CF_REPO_NAME}}
      - GITHUB_REF=${{CF_REVISION}}
      - GITHUB_CONTEXT=Codefresh CI - Build
      - GITHUB_STATE=success
      - GITHUB_TARGET_URL=${{CF_BUILD_URL}}
  on_fail:
    title: Set GitHub deployment status to "failure"
    image: cloudposse/github-status-updater
    environment:
      - GITHUB_ACTION=update_state
      - GITHUB_TOKEN=${{GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      - GITHUB_OWNER=${{CF_REPO_OWNER}}
      - GITHUB_REPO=${{CF_REPO_NAME}}
      - GITHUB_REF=${{CF_REVISION}}
      - GITHUB_CONTEXT=Codefresh CI - Build
      - GITHUB_STATE=failure
      - GITHUB_TARGET_URL=${{CF_BUILD_URL}}
  on_elected:
    title: Set GitHub deployment status to "pending"
    image: cloudposse/github-status-updater
    environment:
      - GITHUB_ACTION=update_state
      - GITHUB_TOKEN=${{GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      - GITHUB_OWNER=${{CF_REPO_OWNER}}
      - GITHUB_REPO=${{CF_REPO_NAME}}
      - GITHUB_REF=${{CF_REVISION}}
      - GITHUB_CONTEXT=Codefresh CI - Build
      - GITHUB_STATE=pending
      - GITHUB_TARGET_URL=${{CF_BUILD_URL}}
```

To disable default status updates patch the pipeline spec with CLI

`codefresh get pip <name> -o yaml > file.yml`

```yaml
spec:
  options:
    enableNotifications: false
```

`codefresh replace -f file.yml`